# Set availabily of application in App Store using an API

Tags: apple-store

Is it possible to make an uploaded iOS application unavailable to download using an API just like [Play Store](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/v1/users/setAvailableProductSet) ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, Apple does not offer an API similar to the Google Play EMM API.

However, you might be able to use web-scraping to obtain a similar effect, if you really need this functionality. It's not going to be as neat as the Google API, as you would probably need to change your scraping program whenever Apple changes their layouts and functionality.

Comment: Apple *does* offer an API, there just doesn't appear to be an ‘availability’ endpoint since it's neither app metadata nor a binary's status.

Comment: Well, I could have phrased it better - Apple offers lots of different APIs, but they do not offer an API that makes it possible to manipulate already uploaded iOS applications to make them unavailable for download in various countries, or similar.